# Point CMake project to specific include file

Tags: build, opencv, ffmpeg, cmake

I am trying to build OpenCV 2.3.0 with FFMPEG enabled. Since Ubuntu 11.10 only supplies libavcodec/format with version 0.7 and the ticket #1020(link below) indicates that it should work with 0.8.

If I try to compile I get the following error:

```
[ 18%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/cap_ffmpeg.o
In file included from /home/chris/src/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg.cpp:45:0:
/home/foo/src/OpenCV-2.3.0/modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:103:36: fatal error: libavformat/avformat.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

This file lives in `/opt/linux64-debug/include/ffmpeg/libavformat/avformat.h`. I tried pointing make at that with CMAKE_INCLUDE_{DIRECTORY,PATH}, CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH. None of that worked. ( I always used the path `/opt/linux64-debug/include/ffmpeg`.)

https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/ticket/1020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `include_directories()` command. In my CMakeLists.txt file, I use it like this:

```
include_directories(. /opt/special/headers/in/here)

add_executable(helloworld helloworld.c)
```

I have never had any problems with it.